# Post comment to my google plus page via API

Tags: api, google-plus

I have a website that allows users give feedback. I would want to publish user feedback on Google Plus business page/stream. Is there a way I can do this or I have to use Google Share?

I did read Google API and it seems I can post comments but I have also read on Stackoverflow that it is only for Google App. Can someone help/guide me?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible at this time to post to a time line thought he Google+ api

There are a number of issue requests relating to this

1. [Write API for own profile](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=19&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)
2. [Write access to the streams](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=41&q=write%20page&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)
3. [Post New Activity Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=214&q=write%20page&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)